# How to fade in divs in sequence with Javascript (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, sequence, fadein

What i want is to fade in my sidebar boxes after each other on page load by adding a class.

I have tried the following:

```
var a = $(".sidebar-box"), delayTime = 2000;

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function(
        var ai = $(a[i]);
        ai.addClass("fade in");
        console.log(ai);
    ), delayTime);

    console.log(delayTime);
    delayTime += 2000;
}
```

The problem is, by the time the class gets added the first time, `i` already is `4`, so the class only gets added to the last box, when actually it should be added to the first one.

Comment: If you really want them to fade in sequentially then you should have each callback register the next rather than increasing the delay and queuing them all up at the same time.  It would be clearer and more flexible.

Comment: And how would you do that? I'm not that experienced yet with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate function so that variable `i` is copied each time:

```
var a = $(".sidebar-box"), delayTime = 2000;

var func = function(i)
{
    setTimeout(function() {
        var ai = $(a[i]);
        ai.addClass("fade in");
    }, delayTime);
}

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    func(i);
    delayTime += 2000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although you have an error in your setTimeout function. (Missing {}).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a class and animating via CSS, if you are okay with using jQuery's `fadeIn()` method, you can have it like:

```
var a = $(".sidebar-box"), delayTime = 2000, i = 0;

function animateSideBar() {
    if(i >= a.length) return;

    // call fadeIn, and pass this function itself as the completion callback
    $(a[i]).fadeIn(delayTime, animateSideBar);

    i++;
}

animateSideBar(); // start it
```

Comment: Thanks, but I like to do it natively via css.